# How to access an instance of a class created in a step from AfterScenario hook in SpecFlow?

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, specflow

I have a class called "`RollbackManager`", it's used to add some actions from tests and to execute all the actions after tests.

I use SpecFlow for my tests so in order to execute something after tests I use `[AfterScenario]` hook.

**The problem is:** I cannot make `RollbackManager` to be static as I run tests in parallel!

**The question is:** how can I access an instance of RollBackManager class that was created in a SpecFlow step definition from the hooks?

**My current project structure:**

Base class with RollbackManager:

```
public class StepBase : Steps
{
    public RollbackManager RollbackManager { get; } = new RollbackManager();

    protected new ScenarioContext ScenarioContext { get; set; }

    public StepBase(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        RollbackManager = new RollbackManager();
    }
}
```

Example of a step definition class:

```
[Binding]
public sealed class ThenExport : StepBase
{
    public ThenExport(ScenarioContext scenarioContext) : base(scenarioContext)
    {
    }

    [Then(@"export status should contain entities: ""(.*)""")]
    public void ThenExportStatusShouldContain(List<String> commaSeparatedList)
    { 
        RollbackManager.RegisterRollback(() => Console.WriteLine());
    }
}
```

My class with hooks:

```
[Binding]
public sealed class SpecFlowTestsBase 
{

    [AfterScenario]
    public void AfterScenario()
    {
        // here I need my rollbacks craeted in steps
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use a base step class and put hooks into it. Your hooks will get then executed multiple times.

Now to your real question:

To share state between step classes, you can use the Context Injection of SpecFlow.
Every instance of the binding class will get the same instance of the TestState class.

It works like this:

```
public class TestState
{
    public RollbackManager RollbackManager { get; } = new RollbackManager();
}

[Binding]
public sealed class ThenExport 
{
    private TestState _testState;

    public ThenExport(TestState testState)
    {
        _testState = testState;
    }

    [Then(@"export status should contain entities: ""(.*)""")]
    public void ThenExportStatusShouldContain(List<String> commaSeparatedList)
    { 
        _testState.RollbackManager.RegisterRollback(() => Console.WriteLine());
    }
}

[Binding]
public sealed class Hooks
{
    private TestState _testState;

    public ThenExport(TestState testState)
    {
        _testState = testState;
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void AfterScenario()
    {
        _testState.RollBackManager.DoYourStuff();
    }
}
```

You find additional documentation here:
https://specflow.org/documentation/Sharing-Data-between-Bindings/
https://specflow.org/documentation/Context-Injection/

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems it helped! I misunderstood using of context injections. Thanks for your examples.